# VBA trying to render image urls but skip blank cells

Tags: excel, url, vba

I have a macro written to render an image url in column A into the column beside it. The images are large, so I have information in every other cell in column A, and the range in column A has a max number but will vary in size each time. I am tryingt to get the code to skip blank cells, but right now it is showing every other cell instead of skipping all the blanks.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Name()

Dim cell, shp As Shape, target As Range

 myurl = "http://(site)"

   Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a195") ' range with names
   For Each cell in Rng
   If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
       filenam = myurl & cell
       ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select

    Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
     With shp
       .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
       .Width = 600
       .Height = 600
       .Cut
     End With
     Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).PasteSpecial
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

I am able to create the images, but I am creating images for blank cells at the end also that are returning boxes saying "Image Not Available" because the url does not exist. Does anyone know how I can omit the blank cells instead of just omitting every other cell?

If this is confusing, I can give more detail.Thanks

Comment: Are the cells truly blank or zero-length strings returned by a formula; e.g. "" ? If zero-length strings then they are not truly blank and `IsEmpty` cannot be used to determine a valid entry. Try `If CBool(Len(cell.Value)) Then` or more precisely something like `If CBool(InStr(1, cell.Value, ".png", vbTextCompare)) Then`.

Comment: The first option worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are the cells truly blank or zero-length strings returned by a formula; e.g. "" ? If zero-length strings then they are not truly blank and `IsEmpty` cannot be used to determine a valid entry. Try,

```
If CBool(Len(cell.Value)) Then
```

... or more precisely something like

```
If CBool(InStr(1, cell.Value, ".png", vbTextCompare)) Then.
```

Comment: This was originally posted as a comment to the question to verify the nature of the cell data in question. As it appears to be the solution to this situation, I've reposted it as an answer.